# Color segmentation

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I need to segment the image by 7 colors (red, orange, yellow, green, light-blue, blue, violet) as in the rainbow. Do you know how to do it? Any papers or algorithms may be. For example it can be done by assigning each triple (r, g, b) a color. But it is not effective as we got there 255^3 of combinations.

Comment: I don't understand your question - you want to reduce the image to 7 colors, mapping every color in the image to one of the seven?

Comment: That is usually not called segmentation, it is called quantization.

Comment: Yes, for simplification of the next steps, I want at first to reduce the image colors to 7, or may be +- some more. The aim is to make some grouping by colors. There are many kinds of a blue color (darker, brighter a little bit) and as an example I want for all variations of the blue color to give only one value (r=0, g=0, 255)

Comment: Sorry, don't understand, what do you mean by with or without dithering?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_photography_and_image_processing explains dithering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "H" component of the HSV colourspace http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV, will give you a reasonable number representing the position on a (continuous) rainbow.

Then it is easy enough to divide that continuous space into seven segments of your choice.

Comment: I tried to convert to HSV space, but if the saturation or V space is changed the color can become grey. And how to deal with it? something like threshold values for S and V spaces?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by S and V being changed, I assume you just had some input RGB pixels, and you wanted to group them into seven baskets.  True, whatever algorithm you use,  some of your RGB pixels might be colourless.  To deal with them you either need an eighth colour (grey), or else you can just assign them to one of your seven colours according to some arbitrary rule of your choice.

Comment: The best option is indeed what Adrian says. Introduce an eight "grey" colour, and all pixels with saturation below a certain threshold are assigned to that colour. Note that this will include black and white pixels, and all greys in between.

Comment: @jilles de wit This helps, but using the threshold makes some color which should be identified as for example blue, to become black(or whatever color is selected) if it's Saturation and Value is less than threshold. And threshold can't be set unique for every color. For blue it is one pair of S and V values, for red it is another. Do you have any idea regarding this problem?

Comment: @maximus: The way to think about the HSV colourspace is as a cylinder. V tells you how high up along the cylinder you are, S tells you how far from the center you are and H is an angle that tells you how far around you moved. Colours near the axis of the cylinder (arbitrary V and H, low S) range from black (low V) to white (high V) but regardless of V and H, if you have low S, a slight change in colour can change H enormously. This is why you cut out the core of the cylinder by thresholding S (and just S, not V).

Comment: @maximus: you could cut a more complex core from the cylinder by using some function that relates your threshold for S to H and V. Look into shapes expressed in cylindrical coordinates for ideas (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system)

Comment: I think I am saying the same jilles here, your threshold in S can be a function of H if you like.  Also it is inevitable that bluish-greys will be become blue or grey, you can make the threshold big or small depending on which kind of "error" you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the 7 colors you need, you don't need to use clustering. A sensible starting point would be: For each pixel in the image find which of the 7 colors lies closest to it (using L2 distance on RGB) and assign that closest color to that pixel. You might be able to get better (more perceptually similar) results by converting first to some other color space, like CIE XYZ, however this will require experimentation.

Comment: Seems to be good idea, but will the L2 distance be enough for that? And sorry can you explain please what is meant by L2 distance?

Comment: The template 8 colors were set as (255, 0, 0) for red, (255, 0, 255) for pink.

Comment: Idea is good, but I have many mismatches such like: green color is detected as black. Or the picture of a white paper is taken by the camera with some scattering, and the edges can be detected as light-blue etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the colors are predefined then the solution is just to loop over every pixel and substitute with the closest representative. As [carlosdc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183251/carlosdc) said may be some color space transformation can give better result than just `(r1-r2)**2 + (g1-g2)**2 + (b1-b2)**2`.

To make things faster a possible trick is to trade in some memory and caching the result of a given RGB triplet... i.e.

```
// Initialize the cache to 255
std::vector<unsigned char> cache(256*256*256, 255);

for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
{
    unsigned char *pixel = img + y*w*3 + x;
    for int (x=0; x<w; x++, pixel+=3)
    {
        int r = pixel[0], g = pixel[1], b = pixel[2];
        int key = r + (g<<8) + (b<<16);
        int converted = cache[key];
        if (converted == 255)
        {
            ... find closest representative ...
            cache[key] = converted;
        }
        pixel[0] = red[converted];
        pixel[1] = green[converted];
        pixel[2] = blue[converted];
    }
}
```

If the numbers of colors is small you can use less memory. For example limiting the number of representatives to 15 you need just 4 bits per color entry (half the space) and something like the following would do it

```
std::vector<unsigned char> cache(256*256*256/2, 255);

...
int converted = (key&1) ? (cache[key>>1] >> 4) : (cache[key>>1] & 0x0F);
if (converted == 15) // Empty slot
{
    ...
    cache[key>>1] ^= (key & 1) ? ((converted << 4)^0xF0) : (converted^0x0F);
}
...
```

If on the opposite you know that the number of possible input colors will be small and the number of representatives will be big then a standard `std::map` can be a valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of clustering methods (algorithms)? For example, k-means algorithm. Otherwise, google "image segmentation by colors."

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to look good you'll want to use dithering, e.g. Floyd Steinberg dithering:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering

Comment: I need to reduce the colors, not creating depth.

Comment: @maximus What does "creating depth" have to do with "dithering"? Dithering is a process to spread the error as you reduce colors so instead of mapping, say [Light Purple, Light Purple, Light Purple, Light Purple, Light Purple] to [Red, Red, Red, Red, Red] using a closest color approach you might instead map it to [Red, Blue, Red, White, Blue] using a dithering approach that looks at the accumulated color error. So overall your image looks (if you squint) the same colors as the original image.